# why does my indexOf output -1 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, indexof

```
class Task{
  String name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({this.name, this.isDone = false});

}

class TaskData{
  List<Task> tasks = [
    Task(name: 'Buy milk'),
    Task(name: 'Buy eggs'),
    Task(name: 'Buy bread')
  ];

}

void main(){

  print(TaskData().tasks.indexOf(Task(name: 'Buy milk')));
}
```

why does it print -1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter(Dart) can not compare objects directly as we compare variables like int, strings and other.

We have to do it manually by checking each and every variables are same or not then we can say that both object are same or not.

However, we can compare class object as other variable by using [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable#-readme-tab-) package.

Add [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable#-installing-tab-) package in pubspec.yaml file and then change your class as below. now you will get desire outputs.

```
class Task extends Equatable {
  String name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({this.name, this.isDone = false});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name, isDone];
}
```

Comment: could you explain what you did by overriding. Also, it gives me a warning to set my properties as final but i prefer not to because i do change them in the later part of my code.

Comment: As @NetanZaf  show way you have to override == method and also override hascode to compare object but Equatable do for us, we have to just pass props, so we do not have to write all boilerplate code. you have to make it final because if you make immutable then only we can compare.

Answer (score 1):

Your program prints -1 becuase the `Task` argument you sent to `indexOf()` does not exist in `tasks`. The following explanation is dart-related more than it is flutter-related.

By default, instance of an object in Dart is considered equal to another instance only if those are the same instance. Here, you created two *different* instances, perhaps with the same properties but they are actually independent of each other. In this case both tasks are logically equal but there is no way Dart could know that. Your options are:

**Use a const constructor**

Const constructors in Dart let you create instances that are compile-time constants. If you use such a constructor, Dart will know for sure that after you create a `Task` its properties can never change. Thus, it will be comfortable making the assumption that `Task(name: 'Buy milk')` will always have the same properties of another `Task(name: 'Buy milk')` no matter what (They are equal). Under the hood, Dart uses the same instance for both. To implement this you'll have to change your code as follows:

```
class Task {
  final String name;
  final bool isDone;

  const Task({this.name, this.isDone = false});
}
```

**Override the hashCode and the == operator**

If you don't want Task to be immutable, you should override the current primitive equality check of `Task`. from Dart's documentation:

> The default hash code implementation provides an identity hash—two
>   objects generally only have the same hash code if they are the exact
>   same object. Likewise, the default behavior for == is identity.
>
> If you are overriding ==, it implies you may have different objects
>   that are considered “equal” by your class. Any two objects that are
>   equal must have the same hash code. Otherwise, maps and other
>   hash-based collections will fail to recognize that the two objects are
>   equivalent.

The default hashCode represents the identity of an instance, but we want it to represent its properties in this case. Note that hashCode should not end up being the same for instances with different properties. It generally does not matter how it's implemented as long as this principle is preserved. I'll use the example provided [here](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#implementing-map-keys) to give a possible implementation:

```
@override
int get hashCode {
  int result = 17;
  result = 37 * result + name.hashCode;
  result = 37 * result + isDone.hashCode;
  return result;
}
```

Now override the `==` operator to reflect the changes:

```
 @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other is! Task) return false;
    Task task = other;
    return (task.name == name &&
        task.isDone == isDone);
  }
}
```

Note that Dart genrally recommends to [avoid defining custom equality for mutable classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-custom-equality-for-mutable-classes), and, following this design rule, the first solution I've listed is the easiest to implement.